# Laravel storage link doesn't work after refreshing PC

Tags: php, laravel, hyperlink, storage

after I reinstalled my PC and put my local laravel project back on my PC, the article images don't work anymore.

So all pictures which are linked to `/storage/artikel_bild/{{$article->artikel_bild}}` don't work anymore.

I tried `php artisan storage:link` but the cmd says it's already linked.
What is the problem here?

```
<img src="/storage/artikel_bild/{{$article->artikel_bild}}" alt="Artikel">

'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
        'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
        'url' => env('AWS_URL'),
    ],

],
```

Comment: what's your operating system?

Answer (score -1):

You should try this:

```
<img src="{{storage_path('artikel_bild/')}}{{}}" alt="Artikel">
```

**Updated answer**

```
<img src="{!! storage_path('artikel_bild/') . $article->artikel_bild!!}" alt="Artikel">
```